# Awesome WM: Goodbye UI

Tags: virtualbox, debian, awesome-wm

Sometimes some of my UI's disappear, but the processes they belong to lives on. So far it has happened to gnome-terminal, emacs, eclipse and evince. I've only experienced this behavior with the Awesome Window Manager. Any ideas how to fix it?

**Update**: It has also happened to a popped out Gmail chat window . When I close the main Gmail window, it warns me that the invisible chat window will also be closed.

**Update 2**: I should mention that I'm using Awesome with Debian inside Sun's VM Virtualbox, and the error seems to occur more frequently when the VM leaves/enters fullscreen mode.

Comment: If the UI disappears it's unlikely that the window manager is the cause, since it *manages* only the windows, it does not paint them. Is it possible to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what triggers it. What would cause this other than the WM?

Comment: An application bug or a *theme* bug (since theme engines run native code in-process) could be causing it; many applications will handle a window being unmapped "gracefully" and exit the application gracefully as a result, but if the window gets unmapped "un-gracefully", as in an X11 error, many applications do **not** handle it properly, and simply enter a broken zombie state where no window exists. It's bad error handling in the app, but it shouldn't happen in the first place... try running the app(s) in question in the terminal and capture any error-ish-looking output.

Comment: Also all of the apps you mentioned run GTK of some form: Gmail chat window would run in Firefox or Chrome, which use GTK; Eclipse uses SWT which uses GTK as a backend; gnome-terminal, evince and (I think) emacs all natively use GTK. So definitely look into the possibility of a GTK theme engine problem

Comment: Have you checked your `.xsession-errors` file?

Comment: The only thing in that file is `/etc/gdm3/Xsession: Beginning session setup...`

Comment: The window manager can hide windows completely. That's how virtual desktops work. Try a different window manager.